# Shapefile One-to-Many Relationship in R

Tags: shapefile, r

Is there any way to append a shapefile in a one-to-many relationship with its attributes that R can read? I understand the fix that resides in ArcInfo by creating through `MakeQueryTable`, but as this information is being analyzed in R -- that is unneccessary.

Really, I am trying to understand R's capabilities with one-to-many relationships as well as the limitations it has utilizing shapefiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use "merge" with the all = TRUE argument. However, be very careful if you want to keep the relationship between the data slot and the rest of the slots in the spatial object. You could take an approach where the external data is not actually joined to the spatial objects data slot but queried during whatever analysis is being applied. This is more of a relate approach.

Not sure on what you mean by "limitations it has utilizing shapefiles"? Limitations would be defined by what you want to do in the first place. When you import a shapefile it becomes an sp class object which is becoming a generic class supported by the majority of packages associated with spatial analysis and modeling. If you provide additional information on what your perceived limitations may be the forum can likely address them directly.